# Importing CSV/JSON/XML + images

Tags: add-on, add-on-development, import

I have a CSV that I need to import in a Channel. The CSV contains an id column that is used as part of a naming convention for a series of images associated with each row. For example, say the id was ABC123, then I might have the following images:

- ABC123_001.jpg
- ABC123_002.jpg
- ABC123_003.jpg
- ABC123_025.jpg

How could I import the CSV and the images?

NOTE: The images are in a Matrix field with one mandatory column: the file field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into the EE addon called DataGrab from Brandnewbox?

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab
http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab

There's notes here on how it can support Matrix fields:

http://brandnewbox.co.uk/support/details/datagrab_and_matrix_fields

I've had it used on quite a few large projects with great success so don't see why it wouldn't work for you. Sometimes you need to massage the CSV file prior to the import.

Comment: I've used DataGrab. However, I'm concerned about the images I need to import. Thoughts?

Comment: Ideally this would be information that you would also add to the CSV file, using the {filedir_X}ABC123_025.jpg, where 'X' is the upload preference ID, as the image reference as outlined in the 'Datagrab and Matrix Fields' link above. It also outlines the format in which those Matrix fields could be formatted within the CSV column. Unless I'm not fully understanding the problem.

Comment: The images need to be uploaded where ever it's supposed to be uploaded to (depending on the file upload preferences), resized, etc. That is the normal process of uploading an image. How will that be mimicked when it's being imported instead?

Comment: You import the image reference via CSV and Datagrab. You upload the images to the correct File Upload point via FTP, then Sync the File Upload preferences. If I'm still not understanding, then you may need to explain better in your original post.